# Somar dados vindos do banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql

Estou usando esta função para buscar um campo numa tabela:

```
function rendimentoDia($conexao, $dia) {
$rendimentos = array();
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, "select valor from hospedes where dia = 
$dia");
while($rendimento = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
    array_push($rendimentos, $rendimento);
}
return $rendimentos;
}
```

depois eu uso esse código para exibir na tela os dados:

```
<table class="container">

<?php
    $rendimentos = rendimentoDia($conexao, $dia);

    foreach($rendimentos as $rendimento) :
?>
<tr>
    <td><?= $rendimento['valor']?></td>
</tr>
<?php

   endforeach
?>
</table>
```

Esse campo traz os valores inseridos em um dia, gostaria de somar esse valores e não estou conseguindo, tentei somar usando o array_sum em uma variavel que guardei o rendimento valor, mas não deu certo.. a função está trazendo tudo certo e exibindo, só não consigo somar mesmo. Agradeço a quem puder ajudar

Comment: Se você fazer a soma direto no SQL que trás as informações não da certo ? Por exemplo, fazer o seguinte: ```select SUM(valor) from hospedes where dia = 
$dia```

Comment: Você precisa de todos os valores separados também ou só a soma?

Comment: olá Anderson, vou tentar aqui pelo mysql, só preciso do resultado mesmo, obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, como você disse nos comentários que precisa só do valor total e não dos valores separados, você pode alterar a funcionalidade diretamente na sua query que dará certo, só deixar seu código deste maneira:

```
$rendimentos = mysqli_query($conexao, "select SUM(valor) from hospedes where dia = $dia");
$rendimento = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);

<table>

<?php
while($rendimento = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
?>

<tr>
    <td><?= $rendimento['sum(valor)']; ?></td>
</tr>
        <?php
    }
?>
</table>
```

Pensando na hipotese que você disse que recebe o `$conexao`através de um include e o `$dia` através do date que você declara ( creio que no mesmo arquivo ), estas variaveis vao estar acessiveis, com isso você não precisar declarar uma função e chama-la logo após. Você pode simplesmente montar a sua Query e logo abaixo fazer o while juntamente a sua table para printar o valor da soma da coluna. Você pode colocar as variaveis responsáveis pela sua query no topo do seu arquivo ou mesmo antes da sua table, só não se esqueça de coloca-la entre as tags do PHP.

Comment: Não está dando certo aqui, quando eu tento exibir ele diz que é um array... eu preciso que ele me devolva só o número, tem como?

Comment: Bom, você pode procurar os valores sem declarar que estes são Arrays. Vou editar a resposta.

Comment: Só uma pergunta antes, a variável conexão você recebe via ```include```de algum arquivo ```conexao.php``` por exemplo ? E a variavel ```dia```, você recebe via POST do form ou declara manualmente ?

Comment: eu crio a variavel com o date

Comment: entendi, bom vou editar aqui

Comment: a, o conexao vem de um include sim

Comment: Tente da maneira que coloquei, faça o teste.

Comment: me devolveu esses erros: Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\oni\rendimento_dia_v.php on line 9
Array
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\oni\rendimento_dia_v.php on line 19

Comment: Troquei o fetch_assoc pelo array, tente da maneira que coloquei agora. Se não for, tenho outra solução.

Comment: Francis, agora que percebi. Você estava fazendo um ```foreach```em sua table que era desnecessário, pois você só precisa imprimir o valor total da coluna, e não fazer um looping para colocar todos os valores desta. Com isso, você só precisa declarar sua function e printar o valor na tabela.

Comment: eu tentei com outra função, mas também não consegui....

Comment: Bom, vou fazer de outra maneira e explicar na resposta.

Comment: não deu certo por aí?

Comment: Editei a resposta já, da uma olhada.